# How to pass a string to a blade component?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-components

As an example there is this component:

**resources/views/components/example.blade.php**

```php
<div>
    @if($foo === "bar")
        Bar
    @else
        Foo
    @endif
</div>
```

that I render like

```php
@php
   $foo = "bar";
@endphp
<x-example :foo="$foo" />
```

what is working.
But to have my code looking cleaner, I want to pass the string directly to the component, but the following I tried are not working:

```php
<x-example :foo="bar" />
<x-example :foo='bar' />
<x-example :foo="\'bar\'" />
<x-example :foo="'bar'" />
<x-example :foo=""bar"" />
```

Comment: Hard coded values don't require the `:` before the parameter name; `<x-example foo="bar" />`.

Comment: That's it - thank you. If you could add that as an answer, I'd vote it as resolved

Comment: @JanBoehmer you should take a look at how to pass data to [`Blade Components`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components) which provides some useful examples that should get you started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy mistake to make, as mentioned in the Laravel documentation on [passing data to components](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components);

> You may pass data to Blade components using HTML attributes.
> Hard-coded, primitive values may be passed to the component using
> simple HTML attribute strings. PHP expressions and variables should be
> passed to the component via attributes that use the `:` character as a
> prefix

So update how you use the Blade component as below:

```
<x-example foo="bar" />
```

Comment: just a suggestion, adding a link to the [Laravel Blade Components Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade) would make your answer more powerful and helpful.

Comment: @ths Indeeed. I wasn't going to as you'd already linked to the docs in your comment. I'll add a link regardless as you're correct, it is helpful regardless.  [:

Comment: yes indeed, thank you for having my suggestion considered and making the required changes.